# Apache Camel - EL evaluate element in array

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to evaluate a value in an array using camel el, but this doesn't work. How can I do to get the evaluation right?

```
<c:choice>
    <c:when>
        **<c:el>${ in.body.system.id in [34, 35]}</c:el>**
        <c:bean ref="transformUtils" method="removeUser(${in.body}, '99999')"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:to uri="activemq:queue:systemOk"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choice>
```

Comment: try with this `${ in.body.system.id} in [34, 35]`

Comment: This doesn't generate an error, but the evaluation doesn't work. I have a system that ID is 35, this ID is in the array but the evaluation returns false.

Comment: try logging this `${ in.body.system.id}` what does it print?

Comment: Did ou try using Simple Expression language like this 
`simple("${in.body.system.id} in [34, 35]")`

Comment: The simple worked perfectly. This is the right expression: `<c:simple>${in.body.system.id} in '34,35,36'</c:simple>` using single quotation marks and no blank space between elements. Thank you @pvpkiran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using java config use
`simple("${in.body.system.id} in [34, 35]")`

use this for xml config

```
<c:simple>${in.body.system.id} in '34,35,36'</c:simple>
```